# Read a file that is locked (?) by a other process

Tags: c#

I want to read the content of a file which is opened (and locked?) by a other process.
I tried it with `File.ReadAllText()` and with `new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))` but both methods trigger a IOException.

For example I can open the file with Notepad++ and the content is shown so I think it must be possible too with c#.

Comment: What is the exception message of the `IOException` object?

Comment: "The process can't access the file '...', because it is used by another process."

Comment: What happens if you also pass `FileShare.Read` to the `FileStream` constructor (at the end)?

Comment: Same problem, @SimonWhitehead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the FileStream constructor overload that takes a `FileShare` argument. And pass `FileShare.ReadWrite`.  You can only open the file if you permit write access since the other program already acquired that right.  Otherwise the reason that your attempts failed so far, they used FileShare.Read.  Can't work, you cannot deny write access because the other program already got that.

Dealing with the program writing to the file while you are reading it is entirely up to you. Results can be quite random.  Anything is possible, but in general for a log file you'll get a partially written last line that's trailing behind the actual output of the program, some of which is still in the program's file buffer.  A buffer size of 4096 bytes is a common choice.

Comment: If other process used `FileShare.None` specifying `FileShare.ReadWrite` also makes no sense right? I guess it will fail? Am I right?

Comment: Surely sharing open files with FileShare.ReadWrite can be problematic as any application, not just your own, can modify the file at any time which could easily screw up your application.

Comment: It still makes sense, I guess, it just isn't going to work.  "None" means what it says, nobody else can open the file.  ReadWrite is already problematic if the file is shared with one process, more of them doesn't make it better.  However, almost any app will open the file to write to it with FileShare.Read to prevent other apps from writing to the file as well.  That just *never* comes to a good end.  When reasoning through the FileShare values, be sure to reverse the roles to make sense of them.